Migrating AutoFac 4.9.1 to Autofac 8.0.0
Recently I am migrating Autofac 4.9.1 to Autofac 8.
Target framework is dotnet framework 4.8. I am facing issue while injecting Logger.
In older version I have LoggerModule module which is responsible for injecting Logger
public class LoggerModule : Autofac.Module
{
   protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
   {
      registration.Preparing += (object sender, PreparingEventArgs e) => {
        var type = e.Component.Activator.LimitType;
        /* using reflection check if there is a constructor with
           parameter of type Logger and if so then create logger
           and setup in constructor
         */
      };
   }
}

After updating to Autofac version 8, above code is giving below compilation error

'LoggerModule.AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)': no suitable method found to override
'IComponentRegistration' does not contain a definition for 'Preparing'

Is there a way to resolve it?

https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ check "Upgrading from" links - one by one, from older to newer.
